# Validation of viewstate MAC failed. on LOCALHOST debug

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\Users\bugnuker\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\771d6925\611b9777\App_Web_dgowrw1y.1.cs    Line: 0 

Stack Trace: 


[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate.     Client IP: ::1  Port: 1121  Referer: http://localhost:57816/Login   Path: /Login    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36   ViewState: JPfkUk+QP/buQafjKxZm8yi572DS6/obP0Cr4ssy46v6WPqlUOh7v4r6tpUcA06p/I1TFpKjfk8lhoqM6zWrxpa7GwAlRT7CpyBk/jQ+6JYK1LlC/f03x04r6miYG0uohqA3f8L5AvBUFBeG5E5IWvBp3g6RjWAhXyv/NJvbzJZjdp7Qjm6DUEdnbbz8ewYW1dI4+Q==]
```

This project was working fine for months. All the sudden, as of this morning, I am getting this error.

I've added the machine key into the web config just to try it out, but I'm using Visual Studio debugger (IIS Express) and I still get the error. I still get the error when I publish to a hosting service.

I've searched all over and I can't find anything about this on a localhost debug. Every solution is to turn off MACValidation - and I'm not doing that - or to add the web.config machineKey element, and I've done that with no success.

If anyone has any ideas at all, I am all ears.

Comment: Hey, I realize it's been a while, but did you find the solution? I am in similar situation now